# Migrating from (now obsolete) custom ATImage content type

Tags: plone, archetypes

We had a whole collection of Plone 3 sites with a custom Image type
subclassed from ATImage. This allowed us to add an extra image scaling to the
standard list ("'logo':(454, 58)", used by our theme package).

While this still works in Plone 4, it isn't really the correct approach now that
plone.app.imaging is part of the standard toolkit. That can define custom scales on
the fly.

It looks like I can enable plone.app.imaging on any type subclassed
from ATImage by simply setting "sizes = None" for the collection of custom
scales on the type. I am however then left with a redundant subclass of ATImage.
Looking long term, it would be useful to replace all of our existing "FalconImage"
content items (hundreds in total) with standard "Image" content items.

A brief experiment on a test site reveals that if I just walk through the document
tree updating the portal_type attribute from "FalconImage" to "Image" then
the content behaves as an "Image": each object suddenly acquires a
Transform tab and all of the scales defined by @@imaging-controlpanel.

I am sure that there would be fallout from such a brute force approach.
Is there a recommended approach for transforming one type into another?

(I'm happy to add source for our custom ATImage type if anyone thinks that
it is relevant. It is really just a very minimal tweak of ATImage, with a
different collection of sizes on the ImageField)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a recommended approach:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration

The only thing that you have to do is to write a custom migration from FalconImage to Image.

Bye,
Giacomo

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Products.contentmigration`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration) but the docs there are no place to start.  Use the [docs at plone.org](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/migrate-custom-types-with-products.contentmigration) for a step-by-step on migrating content.

Comment: Sadly that link is redirected now to https://docs.plone.org/ (dropping all path information); see [Changed documentation locations](https://community.plone.org/t/changed-documentation-locations/4252/8?u=tobiasherp). You don't by chance know a working URL?

Comment: Nope, I can't find it anymore either, @Tobias

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Giacomo and Ross for the pointers.

Just in case it is useful to others, my migration code ended up looking like the following:

```
from Products.contentmigration.walker import CustomQueryWalker
from Products.contentmigration.archetypes import InplaceATItemMigrator

class FalconImageMigrator(InplaceATItemMigrator):
    walker = CustomQueryWalker
    src_meta_type = "FalconImage"
    src_portal_type = "FalconImage"
    dst_meta_type = "ATBlob"
    dst_portal_type = "Image"

    # Following stolen from plone.app.blob.migrations, ATImageToBlobImageMigrator
    # migrate all fields except 'image', which needs special handling...
    fields_map = {
        'image': None,
    }

    def migrate_data(self):
        self.new.getField('image').getMutator(self.new)(self.old)

    # ATFileToBlobMigrator reindexes certain fields. Otherwise we
    # need to clear and rebuild the entire catalog.
    def last_migrate_reindex(self):
        self.new.reindexObject(idxs=['object_provides', 'portal_type',
           'Type', 'UID'])

migrator = FalconImageMigrator
walker   = migrator.walker(portal, FalconImageMigrator)

walker.go()
print walker.getOutput()
```

Complications:

1. Image is a little odd as a destination type, as data gets migrated into the blob store.
2. We need to update the catalog so that "resolveuid/UID" links generated by TinyMCE
   continue to work. last_migrate_reindex() method on Migrator class should be faster than clearing and rebuilding the entire catalog from scratch.