# Converting Archetype Content to Folderish

Tags: plone

I have an archetype content type that previously was not folderish.  Now I have set it as folderish.  What attribute or properties need to be changed so that any data created before can be migrated?

I have read the following documents:

[Generic Setup Upgrade Steps](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html#upgrade-steps)

[Converting one Content Type into another](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/archetypes/converting-content-types.html)

I followed the above tutorial on upgrade steps but I do not know which attribute or properties to change.

Comment: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/zope/message/158655

Changing class can be a problem. What error do you have just tryng to load the old objects? If you just add the folderish class to base class and don't remove anything, it should work.

Comment: Sorry. I no longer recall the error.  I was expecting it at that time so did not take note of it yet.  I just revisited the system and for some reason, it now works.  The old data is now folderish and is rendered fine by its view templates.  The only thing that was changed in the code was its inheritance of ATContentTypeSchema.  The code now inherits from ATFolderSchema.  So I guess the previous error was caused by something else. The site though was updated from Plone 4.1.2 to Plone 4.1.4 recently.

Comment: I did it too, so I'm quite sure it should have worked :)

Comment: Not quite.  Upon further investigation, I noticed that the old data does not have the "add new" in its task bar.  So I think I need Products.contentmigration for this.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. But the old content did not just fix itself.  I found out that the code was not updated to the ATFolderSchema that is why it was rendering the data.  When the updated code was applied, a TypeError occurred.  The templates were looking for the _tree attribute which was missing.  I discovered the update schema tab in archetypes_tool.  Running it added some attributes to the old data but the _tree attribute was still missing. So Products.contentmigration is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Products.contentmigration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration/). See it's doc to find out how to use it, it shouldn't be too difficult: just define your `CustomQueryWalker` and the mapping between your two content types. In order to find out what field you have to map, just put a `pdb` somewhere in the content's view and inspect the content schema.

similar question here: [Migrating from (now obsolete) custom ATImage content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255932/migrating-from-now-obsolete-custom-atimage-content-type)

Comment: Instead of using pdb, I just downloaded sample xml (via export in the ZMI) from the old data and the new one.  I see different fields that are present in the new but not in the old.  So I need to add these attributes to the old?

Comment: Nope, just map the ones that you want to maintain

Answer (score 2):

i stumbled accross the same issue when trying to migrate non-folderish types to folderish ones based on: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.folderishtypes

that helped: on a context to convert, call @@migrate-btrees view [1] to initialize the btree structure [2]. I assume your new Archetype content is plone.app.folder based.

[1] defined in: plone.app.folder.migration.BTreeMigrationView.

[2] Main work is done by: Products.BtreeFolder2.BTreeFolder2Base._initBtrees.